# When should I use profiles in my web app?

Tags: asp.net

When would I use profiles in my web app?

Comment: @ Oded: what in the world is that link for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx):

> A good web site will remember me.
>   Perhaps the site will remember my
>   favorite color scheme, or my preferred
>   shipping address. Either way, if a
>   site makes me feel like I’m not just
>   another IP address on the web, I’m
>   more likely to return in the future.
>   Adding a personal touch for your
>   end-users can make a difference.

Use Profiles to enhance the experience of your website, read more about [ASP.NET Profile Properties on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at64shx3%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).